Having trouble deploying android app to same tablet from multiple PCs
I have two PCs that I use to develop my app with a git repository to share code, and I sometimes have trouble the first time I deploy my app after switching PCs.
To give a specific example: I've been using PC 1 for a few weeks with no issues deploying. Today I pushed code to the repository from PC 1 and pulled on PC 2, but when I tried deploying from PC 2 I got java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 2 to 1 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) and my app instantly crashed.
After that, I tried re-deploying again from PC 1, but now on that one I'm getting the device already has an application with the same package but a different signature with the option to re-install and lose all application data.
My app has progressed to the point that I want some sort of stability and not lose application data as I progress, so I guess my questions are two fold:

Is there some file I can transfer from PC 2 to PC 1 so that they have the same signature? I thought I was using the right gitignore (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Android.gitignore) but I dunno if there's some other file containing the signature that I'm missing that would allow me to redeploy from PC 1 without losing all data.
Is there a way to specifically see what database schemas Android Studio sees when it attempts to deploy? Admittedly, I've erased all schemas a few times in development just to avoid having a bunch of migrations, but I haven't had a version 2 in a few weeks and I don't know what schemas version 2 and 1 refer to in order to write a migration.


Update: I was able to answer the first question with information found at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode. The solution was to copy  C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore from PC 2 to PC 1, and that fixes the device already has an application with the same name but a different signature error. However, now deploying from PC 1 gives me the same A migration from 2 to 1 was required but not found error and I am still unsure how to figure out what schemas Android Studio thinks exists.
